# Pop up to be opened on dropdownlist change event

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup, ddl

I'm trying to create a pop up window which is triggered upon selecting an option from a dropdownlist using JQM .

The popup datarole:

```
 <!--popup window inside index page -->
    <div data-role="popup" id="puProd"> TODO POP UP STUFF </div>
```

And this is the JS code:

```
$(document).ready("#index", function (event) {
$("#ddlSelectProduct").on("change", function () {
    $("#puProd").popup("open");
});
```

Am I doing something wrong? Because the pop up won't open.

Will appreciate answers
Thank you

Comment: @Homen the first part is the html code

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery Mobile **[pagecreate event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/)** instead of document ready:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#index", function(){ 
    $("#ddlSelectProduct").on("change", function () {
            $("#puProd").popup("open");
    });
});
```

## **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/vKbvNV)**